# Cannot close fancybox from server side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I tried this:

```
if (pdfDocumentinBytes!= null)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content", "attachment; filename=" + this.documentName + ".pdf");
    Response.BinaryWrite(pdfDocumentinBytes);
    Response.End();
}

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "fancyboxClose();", true);
```

`fancyboxClose()` is a function which just closes the fancy box when called from server side.

Comment: need to close the fancybox after response.end

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why are you trying to close a modal window from the server?

Comment: because a pdf is downloaded after response ends and i need to time it with the download.so